# Как можно интегрировать динамически подгружаемый список в слайдер?

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, css

Всем привет! Есть список динамический подгружаемый список, срабатывающий при клике на кнопку вида:

```
<ul>
   <li>Item</li>
   <li>Item</li>
</ul>
```

и есть адаптивный слайдер

```
<div id="owl-carousel" class="owl-carousel">
    <div>Слайд1</div>
    <div>Слайд2</div>
    <div>Слайд3</div>
</div>
```

- как их можно совместить так, чтобы элементы списка помещались в элементы карусели и все отлично отрабатывало? Целый день ломаю голову как это сделать - не поможете? как не крути - толи дивами лишки оборачивать, толи наоборот и при любых конструкциях система ломается..

Answer (score 1):

При клике добавьте "нужности" в слайдер (можно это например сделать с помощью jQuery -  [append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/)). А затем проинициализируйте слайдер еще раз прям из js.

Comment: что-то я не сильно врубаюсь- как это  проинициализируйте слайдер еще раз прям из js? можно поподробнее?

Comment: Допустим слайдер инициализируется так: $('div').slider(); Мы добавляем что нам нужно в html и еще раз вызываем $('div').slider();